# How to not start WebView in SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

It is a similar question to the following.

When the application is started from the push notification specified by OpenDirect while the application is Inactive, both the WebView in the SDK and the WebView specified by you will start up.
I want to prevent WebView in the SDK from starting, but before handling push notification as in the solution to the above question
[[ETPush pushManager] setOpenDirectDelegate: self];
I am doing, but WebView in the SDK will start up.

It seems that WebView in the SDK is running before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but please tell me specific solution.

Comment: [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141054/opendirect-etinternallandingpagepresenter)`https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141054/opendirect-etinternallandingpagepresenter`

Comment: Are you implementing the methods of `ExactTargetOpenDirectDelegate` in your delegate?

Comment: Yes, we implement `ExactTargetOpenDirectDelegate` in delegate.
It also implements the `didReceiveOpenDirectMessageWithContents` method and the` shouldDeliverOpenDirectMessageIfAppIsRunning` method.
As I was debugging, the `didReceiveOpenDirectMessageWithContents` method was called on WebView in the SDK.
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: What SDK version are you using so I can verify against the code?

Comment: In your implementation of the delegate, you are calling `[[ETPush pushManager] setOpenDirectDelegate:self]` first, correct? And then, in `shouldDeliverOpenDirectMessageIfAppIsRunning` you return YES? Those in combination will lead to the path of the delegate ONLY handling the presentation of the open direct message.

Comment: The SDK version I am using is 4.5.1. [[ETPush pushManager] setOpenDirectDelegate: self] is called immediately after [[ETPush pushManager] configureSDKWithAppID ...]. Are you calling in the wrong position? Also, shouldDeliverOpenDirectMessageIfAppIsRunning returns NO.

Comment: Ah, I believe the issue is related to `-shouldDeliverOpenDirectMessageIfAppIsRunning` - that should return YES to override the internal behavior of the SDK. From the ETPush.h header (most recent version, although I think older versions have the same comment): ```If set to YES, the OpenDirect delegate will be called if a push with an OpenDirect payload is received and the application state is running. ```

Comment: I set it to return YES with `shouldDeliverOpenDirectMessageIfAppIsRunning`, but WebView in the SDK still starts up.
By the way, I set `setOpenDirectDelegate` with` didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, but are you mistaken?

Comment: Would you please post some more snippets of your implementation? Specifically, your method where you `setOpenDirectDelegate`, `shouldDeliverOpenDirectMessageIfAppIsRunning` and `didReceiveOpenDirectMessageWithContents`.